# PHP output directory folders, Files and echo Permissions and if writable or unwritable

Tags: php

I would like PHP to check the directory of selection i input in variable and out put the Folder, Files, Permission (writable or not writable) at same time.

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$directorySelection = '../app/';
if (file_exists($directorySelection)) {
  if ($existence = opendir('../app')) {
    while (false !== ($files = readdir($existence))) {
      if ($files  != "." && $files  != ".." && $files  != ".DS_Store") {
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="width: 90%; padding: 10px;">'. $files .'</td>';
        if (is_writable($files)) {
          echo '<td><span class="label label-success">Writable</span></td>';
        } else {
          echo '<td><span class="label label-danger">Not writable</span></td>';
        }
        echo '<td>'. substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($files)), -4) . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
      }
    }
    closedir($existence);
  }
} else {
  echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Application Directory doesn\'t exist <a role ="button"  data-toggle="alertInfo" placement="left" title="Application Directory" data-content="Please set your Application Directory, so that the installer can check for folder, files and there Permissions "> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign floatRight"></span></a></div>';
}
?>
```

**Result i get:**
 [image]

Comment: And what output do you expect to get? What is the error?

Comment: I get 0 for all Permissions and 'Not writable' for all folders as you can see in picture

Comment: Are you checking for errors? If not, use [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: No not checking for errors, just want to know why is not echoing the actual file permission for each folder.

Comment: If you're not checking for errors, how do you know if your code contains errors or not? You're just assuming there are no errors in it; are there?

Comment: cause is echoing what i want it to echo, but is echoing wrong format ('0' instead of example '755').

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did check for error but no error was showing.

Comment: Ah, I see this question got solved too ;) Another happy ending.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes sir, i feel so rookie with PHP, but i get there. if i can master other languages, then i should be able to do this too :)

Comment: I too was once a rookie. I'm no pro (by far), yet I do pretty well for myself. If I don't know how to do it, I'll spend as much time on Google as my patience will let me; it's rather broad, yet sometimes I just give it a rest & let it sink in a bit. I find that just thinking away from the computer often helps to resolve issues. I appreciate the comment you gave me earlier in regards to *"your stuff (answer) always work for me man. I don't understand anyone else well."* - Yeah, I can still see your other question lol - `10k+` members can see deleted questions haha. So, you ended up deleting it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol Yeah man, i didn't wanna make the community bad with easy questions like mine. :) okay from now on i too will step away from computer for while maybe that will help me too :?.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wohoo i got the privilege to chat now.

Comment: It wasn't an easy question, since there were a lot of questions that needed to be asked when something isn't clear. Even the pros get it wrong (there's a hidden message here, not aimed at you, nor me) lol - However, it ended up being solved and that's the important thing. A lot of guys don't ask enough questions, which can potentially lead to a solution; which was the case tonight.

Comment: Yeah, I know ;) Gee, I wonder why? lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58925/discussion-between-fred-ii-and-brian-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with your `$files` variable, as it doesn't contain the full path, only the name, and it is checking from CWD.

Your code is testing for the file perms based on the CWD, but your files are not located in the CWD.  so prefix the `$files` with the name of the directory such as

```
 if ($files  != "." && $files  != ".." && $files  != ".DS_Store") {
   $filepath = $directorySelection . $files;
   .... 
   if (is_writable($filepath)) {
   .....

  substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($filepath)), -4)
```

And it should read the file correctly.  Then use `$files` if you want the name, and `$filepath` for function that take a filename. 
(interior code not shown as to not clutter it up)

Comment: Thanks, Yes that make it work for permissions. but how about writable or Not writable. do i also have to set that to path? @Doon

Comment: +1 I had a feeling that `substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($files)), -4)` had something to do with it.

Comment: see my latest edit, move the path up and then use filepath for functions, and $files for the name.

Comment: @doon it show as not writable still, but the permissions are `755`

Comment: Unless php is running as the same user as the owner of the file. That would be correct. In most cases php runs as a non priv account (www,nobody) so first make sure that the owner of the php process is owner of the file.

Comment: Im in localhost on mac, i believe that makes it owner of the file.@Doon

Comment: your welcome. I just looked on OSX, apache is configured to run as _www, so if you are looking at files you own mode 755, then they would not by writeable.